# /tp Relative Coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As most minecraft command makers know, entering `~` instead of a coordinate number results in the relative position of the executing entity. Apparently, the `/tp` command has a special property with relative coordinates.

I am trying to make a command that teleports all other entities to the same position as the player, but on a absolute Z value. This will make a third person, 2D-looking effect. Here's my command:

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[type=!Player,r=20] ~ ~ -645
```

This does not work. In the `/tp` command, it appears that the `~`s are no longer relative to the executing entity, but the entity being teleported.

A similar command works like I expect it to. It places a  block at the player's position, but again at a fixed z position:

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~ -650 minecraft:stone
```

I am wondering how to make the `~`s in the `/tp` command to execute relative to the executing entity, not the entity being teleported.

Both the commands are inside a repeating, non-conditional, redstone-requiring command blocks. They are both powered by levers.

I am on Minecraft 1.12 Mac edition, singleplayer world.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ /teleport @e[type=!player,r=20] ~ ~ -645
```

`teleport` is a command added in 1.10 that behaves exactly like `tp`, except that coordinates are relative to the executor.

Comment: This works, but /teleport does not take absolute coordinates. I need a solution that can take both relative AND absolute. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: @yummypasta It certainly does, I just tested.

Comment: Interesting... my command `/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /teleport @e[type=!Player] ~ ~ -645` does not move the entity's z axis at all... it stays in it's initial Z position. The command should teleport it to the -645 position on Z. This is strange, as I just did some more testing to find that it does indeed take absolute values. Is this a bug?

Comment: `execute @p ~ ~ ~ teleport @e[type=chicken] ~ ~ -45` works absolutely fine for me. the chicken always was at -45 in the z axis, following my movement in the x and y axis.

Comment: Must have been a glitch in my commands/typo. It now works. I accepted your answer. Thanks!